# Why a pair of electrons with $E<E_F$ is a bound state

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, superconductivity

Cooper pairs have energy $E<2 E_F$. So we say that Cooper pair is a bound state.

But I don't understand this.

For me a bound state is a stated localised in the space and I don't see the link between $E<2 E_F$ and we have a localised state.

Answer (score 2):

It just means that to put those two electrons into the state of two free electrons, they'd each need an energy above the Fermi level, so the total energy would need to end up above twice that.  Since the energy starts out less than that, this means energy would need to be provided to the electrons.  So that's a bound state-- a state that requires that energy be added to make a free state.  The limits on range of motion have more to do with correlations between where the two electrons can go, than it does with the total volume they are confined to.  And remember that a completely unbound particle can still have a non-definite momentum, such that it can be confined to a very small and moving "wave packet" at any given moment, yet still be a "free" particle.

Comment: "It just means that to put those two electrons into the state of two free electrons, they'd each need an energy above the Fermi level"

I don't understand this. Why a free electron should have an energy higher than the Fermi energy ? For me the fermi energy is just the higher energy of a system of N electrons. But all thoose electrons can be free (and thus a free electron can have $E<E_F$).

Comment: You know the Cooper pair cannot be free electrons because they have an energy  already occupied by  electrons that actually are free, violating the Pauli exclusion principle.  The correlations between the electrons in the pair (imposed by interactions with  the lattice) do two things: they lower the energy of the pair, and they allow the pair to exist at that lower energy by making the pair act like a boson-- freeing it from the PEP.   So it is a bound state because its energy is below what two free electrons would need, and because the electrons are correlated to act like a boson state.

Answer (score 1):

The bound energy $E_b = E-2E_F$ can have a characteristic length scale $\xi$,  from the estimation $E_b=-\frac{\hbar^2}{m\xi^2}$, this $\xi$ has the physical meaning for the localized in the space as you mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 1):

To expand just a little on Ken G's answer, when one says that a Cooper pair is a bound state, what is meant is that it is a state with energy less than the continuum. In other words, one must add energy to a cooper pair to separate it into two electrons.

As to why it takes energy to break up a cooper pair, suppose we start with a Fermi gas of electrons such that all states of energy $E<E_F$ are filled and all above are empty. We want to ask, if we add two new electrons to this system is it more energetically favorable to for them to just fill up free electron states or to form a cooper pair.

Since all states below the Fermi surface are filled each new electron would be placed in a state of energy $E_0 \sim E_f$ and the total energy cost of adding the two particles is $E \sim 2E_f$. This is just the statement that $E_F = \mu$ is the chemical potential of a Fermi gas at zero temperature, i.e. the amount of energy needed to add a particle to the system.

On the other hand we can calculate the energy of a cooper pair as some quantity $E_c$. If $E_c < 2E_f$, then it is energetically favorable for the two added particles to form a cooper pair.